# How can I change a dependency import depending on the request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an internal form service that collects payments via Stripe. I'm curious how I can toggle between test mode and live mode with their SDK based on a query param?

Here's an example route:

```
router.post("/:formId", function(req, res, next) {

    let isTest = false
     var stripeSdk = require("stripe")(process.env.stripe_client_secret);
    if (req.query.test === "true") {
      stripeSdk = require("stripe")(process.env.stripe_client_test_secret);

      isTest = true;
        }

//use the sdk with either test or live mode depending on the call
});
```

The code above works, but I'm curious if there's a better way to change an npm package import based on the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write:

```js
const isTest = (req.query.test === "true");
const stripeSecret = isTest ? process.env.stripe_client_test_secret : process.env.stripe_client_secret;
const stripeSdk = require('stripe')(stripeSecret);
```

But I guess it is more a matter of taste than anything else.

I don't think it gets more fancy than that.

Comment: That’s what I was thinking. Do you think I should be worried doing an import inside a route? I wonder if it will cause a large amount of memory to be consumed since it imports it every time a request is made.

Comment: Modules are cached after they are loaded so It shouldn't be a problem (cf. [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching)).